# Record and email audio files on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

is it possible to record the sound in iPhone 2.1 and then attache it in mail? I have to record any sound on one button click. Please help for that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the iPhone 2.1 SDK does not have any APIs to attach an audio clip in mail.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could do this if you wrote your own email app and were able to properly encode the data from our audio file as an attachment.  From what I have read the current sandbox environment for the Mail is only allowed to look into pictures for attachments.

Comment: ok thanks can you help me for audio recording using objective-c